# Do we see depictions of the Cylon god?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, caprica, blood-and-chrome

I was reading up on the Imperious Leader, which lead to Count Iblis, which led to this comment on Wikipedia:

> Count Iblis was not specifically named as part of the 2003 remake of Battlestar Galactica. **However, the Cylon God, which is often discussed in the series, bears a close resemblance to Iblis.**

But when in BSG Reimagined do we see depictions of the Cylon god? I can't tell if this line from Wikipedia means "resembles him in character" or "resembles him in appearance".

Is there any Cylon art on the ships or Earth or anywhere that we see a depiction of their god?

It's been said that this image from *Caprica* may have an image of the god:

[image]

But on closer inspection, it's just a flower:

[image]

Comment: http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Cylon_Religion

Comment: @Valorum See update.